# bootstrap 4 show tabs doesn't work after first click

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tabs

I work with bootstrap 4 tabs for show form(content tab) like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
   <div id="newsletter">
     <div class="newsletter">
       <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="list-unstyled">
           <li class="active">
             <a href="#newsletter_email" data-toggle="tab" class="newsletter_email"></a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#newsletter_mobile" data-toggle="tab" class="newsletter_mobile"></a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="newsletter_email">
           <div class="newsletter_frm">
             <form class="ajax" action="" noscroll="yes">
               <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" class="newsletter_inp" error="" check="email" check_error="">
               <button type="submit" class="newsletter_btn"></button>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="newsletter_mobile">
           <div class="newsletter_frm">
             <form class="ajax" action="" noscroll="yes">
               <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="mobile" class="newsletter_inp" error="" check="mobile" check_error="">
               <button type="submit" class="newsletter_btn"></button>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now, In action bootstrap tab only work in first change(click in icon for show content tab) and after this doesn't work. how do fix this problem?

[Demo HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Alakian/w8yscfox/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `nav` class to `<ul>` which is having `list-unstyled` class.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled nav">
```